# Getting the text of first <p> tag and check for successful login in an automation test script in Mocha and Selenium

Tags: selenium, mocha.js

I am having an automated testing script which I am trying to run using *mocha* on *selenium* environment.

The script first logs in, then checks the text of the all `<p>` tag.

If the text of any of the `<p>` tag matches the phrase "*"Welcome to the admin page!"*" then the login attempt will be considered successful. Else it's a failed attempt.

I want to change the code. Instead of iterating through all the

tags, I just need to check with the first

tag. How can I do that?

I want to record the details, whether the attempt is successful or failed one.

My code is given below.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var equals = webdriver.equals;

test.describe('TrackRevenue Test', function() 
{
  test.it('should work', function() 
  {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
                    .build();
        var loginFlag = 0;
        var baseUrl = 'http://saswatr3.ouh.co/login';
        var expectedTitle = "Track Revenue";
        var successMessage = "Welcome to the admin page!";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
            if(expectedTitle === title)
            {
                console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
        });
        driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys('saswat@matrixnmedia.com');
        driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys('DarkPrince2012');
        driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
        driver.wait(until.titleIs('Track Revenue'), 1000);
        driver.findElements(By.tagName('p')).then(function (pTag) 
        {
            pTag.forEach(function(p) //I am iterating through all the <p>. I need to get only the first <p>
            {
                p.getText().then(function(text) 
                {
                    if(text.toLowerCase() === successMessage.toLowerCase())
                    {
                        loginFlag = 1;
                    }
                    //done(); //mocha async callback
                }); 
            });
            if(loginFlag ==1)
                console.log("Login Successful");
            else
                console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
        });
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

The html section of the `<p>` section having "Welcome to the admin page!"

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-centered col-xs-12">
     <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
     <div class="ibox-title">
       <h5>Links</h5>
       <div class="ibox-tools"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="ibox-content">
        <p>Welcome to the admin page!</p>
        <p>Please use the menu on the left</p>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

PS.

I need some more modification in the code. In any case, if the login fails, then the login page has div which displays the text : "*Invalid credentials.*"

The html of the section is like this:

```
<div class="text-danger text-danger-orange">Invalid credentials.</div>
```

I want to have a check script which detects this section as well.

#### EDIT:

When I am putting this piece of script, then my script runs fine:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Welcome to the admin page!')]")).then(function()
        {
            loginFlag = 1;
            if(loginFlag ==1)
                console.log("Login Successful");
            else
                console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
        });
```

But when I am putting this piece of script, I am getting an
*Type Error: Undefined is not a function*

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Welcome to the admin page!')]")).size() != 0)
{
   loginFlag = 1;
}
else
{
    //"Welcome to the admin page" not found
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Invalid Credentials!')]")).size() != 0)
    {
        //do what you have to do if "Invalid credentials" is found
    }
    else
    {
        // "Invalid credentials not found"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your life easier with using XPATH. For example:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//* [text()[contains(.,'Welcome to the admin page!')]]")).size() != 0){
            //do what you have to do if "Welcome to the admin page" is found
        }else{
            //"Welcome to the admin page" not found
            if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//* [text()[contains(.,'Invalid credentials')]]")).size() != 0){
                //do what you have to do if "Invalid credentials" is found
            }else{
                // "Invalid credentials not found"
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

As you wish a little elaboration:

With xpath you can simply just search for the desired text which should occur on your page. If you just want to look for the string *"Welcome to the admin page"* or *"Invalid credentials"* regardless of the position on the page you can easily search a text by:

```
//* [text()[contains(.,'<your string text here>')]]
```

It checks if the `getText()` method of a node contains the given text.

If you want to check the whole page if there is a result you can use `findElements` because it will return *all* found WebElements. If there is nothing found with the given xpath it return an empty "array" with size 0. So if you use

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//* [text()[contains(.,'Welcome to the admin page!')]]")).size() != 0
```

you can check if the method has found an element with the desired text.

That is all, the other stuff is just simple if/else.. you can use the above mentioned xpath and function as you like. So instead of iterating trough ALL you `<p>` tags you can simple just use the above mentioned xpath.

**EDIT2:**

with mocha you could try doing something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Welcome to the admin page!')]")).then(function(elements_arr)
    {
        if(elements_arr.length > 0){
            //your element got found
            console.log("Login Successful");
        }else{
            //your element was not found
            console.log("Login Unsuccessful");

            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Invalid Credentials!')]")).then(function(elements_arr2)
            {
               if(elements_arr2.length > 0){
                  //your element invalid credentials got found
                  console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials found");
               }else{
                 //your element was not found
                 console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials not found");
               }
            });
        }         
    });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this?

Comment: @Saswat is this more understandable? If not just explain what you don't understand

Comment: I am geting error.           InvalidSelectorError: {"errorMessage":"The result of the xpath expression \
"//text()[contains(.,'Welcome to the admin page!')]\" is: [object Text]. It shou
ld be an element."

Comment: Ah yes, if you need the element rather a text you should use `//* [text()[contains(.,'<your text here>')]]` .. haven't testes the code before, I will edit it :)

Comment: Now it gives an typeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: but works totally fine for me. You should get the error somewhere else? I haven't checked your other code, so you should find out where you get this exception

Comment: AM I having error due to the html structure? I am sharing my html structure in my question. Please have a look

Comment: In which line does the error occur? How is your current and modified code?

Comment: I will be editing my question with some issues I have faced later. Give me some time. I will explain all in my question.

Comment: Hmm it seems that with mocha this works a little bit different.. i have updated my answer with an approach based on your script. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. :) That helped. Its a charm. (Y)

Comment: Just another Issue happened. Its always stating div login credentials not found, whenever the login is unsuccessfull